# Count number of pipelines in a merge request in GitLab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api, merge-request

In my `.gitlab-ci.yml`, I would like to give an incremental ID to every pipeline executed, but only relative to the merge request (the pipeline-ID is too large for my purposes), so the first pipeline will have a 0 (or 1, depending how I can get this number), the second a 1 (or 2), etc.

I've thought about using the number of *root* pipelines executed at that moment (I'm not sure how to name them, I mean the pipelines launched on a push, tag, etc., but not the downstream ones). I refer to this value:

[image]

I have found a solution using the API (see the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72644849/1485885)), but I would like to know if there is any better way to do it (I'm new in GitLab CI and probably I've just killed a fly with a sledgehammer).

Answer (score 0):

So far I've been able to retrieve the value from the list of pipelines in the MR with [this API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#list-mr-pipelines=):

```
GET /projects/:id/merge_requests/:merge_request_iid/pipeline
```

So, just query the header of that request and parse the total number of items:

```bash
curl --header "JOB-TOKEN: ${CI_JOB_TOKEN}" \
  "${PROJECT_URL}/merge_requests/${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID}/pipelines" \
  --silent --show-error -I | awk '/^x-total:/{print $2}'
```

But I find this solution a bit over-engineered. If you know about any better approach (like a `CI_` variable), I'll be delighted to hear about it.